# How to calculate the solution set for an equation with vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I am given the following task:

> Calculate the the real solution set $L$ for $$(\begin{array}{cc}
>     -10 & 17 & 70 \\
>   \end{array})\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} = 0$$

I really don't understand this task. I would have just said that $x=0, y=0, z=0$. But the solution set should be in the following form:

$$
L=\{\lambda v + \mu w \space | \space \lambda , \mu \in \mathbb{R}\} \text{ with } v,w \in \mathbb{R}^3.  
$$

Or is the first given element a matrix and only the second element a vector? Becaue I just assumed that the first element is a row vector and the second just a column vector. But if the first element is a matrix is still don't know how to calculate the solution set.

Maybe someone here can give me a clue on how to solve this task and maybe give a litte example. I would really appreciate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(-10,17,70)$ has rank $1$, the solution set will have dimension $2$. That is because, in general, for an homogeneous system $Ax=0$ we have
$$\text{dimension of solutions}=\text{n}º\text{ unknowns}-\text{rank}A.$$
Now, since the solution set has dimension $2$, if we know the coordinates $x$ and $y$ of a solution vector $(x,y,z)$, the $z$ coordinate will be determined by $x$ and $y$. So put $x=\lambda$ and $y=\mu$, and get
$$\begin{bmatrix}-10&17&70\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda\\\mu\\z\end{bmatrix}=0\implies z=\frac{1}{70}(10\lambda -17\mu).$$
So every solution is of the form
$$\begin{cases}x=\lambda\\[1ex]
y=\mu\\[1ex]
z=\dfrac{1}{70}(10\lambda -17\mu)\end{cases}\quad \lambda,\mu\in \mathbb{R}.$$
You can obtain $L$ from here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I now have the following solution set:

$$L=\lambda \times \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \frac{1}{70} \times 10 \end{bmatrix} + \mu \times \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ \frac{1}{70} \times -17 \end{bmatrix}$$

Is hope that this is correct and I thank you for your time and your answer.

Comment: I accidentally forgot the brackets that are indicating that it's a set, and in this brackets I should also clarify that $\lambda , \mu \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That's perfect!